# useEffect runs for the old data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to write a singleton class that will act as a local storage wrapper. I need this because wherever I use localstorage in my whole app, I need each of the items I set to have prefix. This prefix for sure changes, but at only one place, so  wrapper seems a good idea so that in my app, I don't have to pass prefix each time I use localStorage.

Here is my wrapper.

```
let instance;

class LocalStorage {

    constructor() {
        if(instance){
          return instance; 
        }
        instance = this;
        instance.cachePrefix = null
    }
    
    _getKey(key, usePrefix) {
        return usePrefix ? `${this.cachePrefix}:${key}` : key;
    }

    setPrefix(prefix) {
        this.cachePrefix = prefix
    }

    set(key, value, usePrefix = true) {
        if(key == null) {
            return
        }
        
        localStorage.setItem(this._getKey(key, usePrefix),value)
    }

    get(key, usePrefix = true) {
        return localStorage.getItem(this._getKey(key, usePrefix));
    }

}

export const LocalStorageWrapper = new LocalStorage()
```

Now, where I import this class and call `setPrefix`, this piece is located in the very parent component tree, so we can say that this `setPrefix` will be called the first time.

**Problem:** Even though I call this `setPrefix` in the very parent, in that very parent, I have async call and when its result gets resolved, that's when I call `setPrefix`. Even though this is very fast, I am still not sure that this will work all the time.. It's possible that before this async call finishes, child component might start to render and it will try to use wrapper that won't have `prefix` set up...

I can't use hooks, because the whole react app is written with classes.

I'd appreciate your inputs what can be done here.

**UPDATE** THIS IS VERY PARENT PROVIDER IN THE TREE.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import BN from 'bn.js'
import { useWallet as useWalletBase, UseWalletProvider } from 'use-wallet'
import { getWeb3, filterBalanceValue } from './web3-utils'
import { useWalletConnectors } from './ethereum-providers/connectors'
import { LocalStorageWrapper } from './local-storage-wrapper'
const NETWORK_TYPE_DEFAULT = 'main'

const WalletContext = React.createContext()

function WalletContextProvider({ children }) {
  const {
    account,
    balance,
    ethereum,
    connector,
    status,
    chainId,
    providerInfo,
    type,
    ...walletBaseRest
  } = useWalletBase()

  console.log("========= ", type);

  const [walletWeb3, setWalletWeb3] = useState(null)
  const [networkType, setNetworkType] = useState(NETWORK_TYPE_DEFAULT)

  const connected = useMemo(() => status === 'connected', [status])

  // get web3 and networkType whenever chainId changes
  useEffect(() => {
    let cancel = false

    if (!ethereum) {
      LocalStorageWrapper.setPrefix(NETWORK_TYPE_DEFAULT)
      return
    }

    const walletWeb3 = getWeb3(ethereum)
    setWalletWeb3(walletWeb3)
    
    walletWeb3.eth.net
      .getNetworkType()
      .then(networkType => {
        if (!cancel) {
          setNetworkType(networkType)
          LocalStorageWrapper.setPrefix(networkType)
        }
        return null
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setNetworkType(NETWORK_TYPE_DEFAULT)
        LocalStorageWrapper.setPrefix(NETWORK_TYPE_DEFAULT)
      })

    return () => {
      cancel = true
      setWalletWeb3(null)
      setNetworkType(NETWORK_TYPE_DEFAULT)
      LocalStorageWrapper.setPrefix(NETWORK_TYPE_DEFAULT)
    }
  }, [ethereum, chainId])

  const wallet = useMemo(
    () => ({
      account,
      balance: new BN(filterBalanceValue(balance)),
      ethereum,
      networkType: connected ? networkType : 'main',
      providerInfo: providerInfo,
      web3: walletWeb3,
      status,
      chainId,
      connected,
      ...walletBaseRest,
    }),
    [
      account,
      balance,
      ethereum,
      networkType,
      providerInfo,
      status,
      chainId,
      walletBaseRest,
      walletWeb3,
      connected,
    ]
  )

  return (
    <WalletContext.Provider value={wallet}>{children}</WalletContext.Provider>
  )
}
WalletContextProvider.propTypes = { children: PropTypes.node }

export function WalletProvider({ children }) {
  return (
    <UseWalletProvider connectors={useWalletConnectors}>
      <WalletContextProvider>{children}</WalletContextProvider>
    </UseWalletProvider>
  )
}
WalletProvider.propTypes = { children: PropTypes.node }

export function useWallet() {
  return useContext(WalletContext)
}
```

Comment: Can you post the parent component where you're calling these class methods?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what your exact issue is, but you said, "It's possible that before this async call finishes, child component might start to render and it will try to use wrapper that won't have prefix set up..." - this is a near-constant concern for front end applications, as we can't really ever guarantee that our data will be fetched by the time our components render. This is why we deal with loading states and conditional rendering based on whether our data has been loaded or not. If the child component checks for the prefix and it hasn't loaded, do you handle that scenario?